# Need help in leveraging MySQL auditing

Tags: mysql, mariadb, security, audit, percona

We are setting up password rotation policy to rotate account/password quarterly. We are also planning to use MySQL/Maria/Percona Auditing. Need to figure out the most efficient and feasible way to achieve both with minimum intervention while at password rotation.

> Explanation: I don't want to edit/add/change audit filter rule every
>   quarter once we rotate user accounts.

Possible tried solutions:

- Tried auditing ROLE with permissions which is attached to application
  accounts (subject to rotation) with NO LUCK as auditing filter based
  on login accounts.
- Configuring exclude_account to (MySQL_schema@localhost) hence logging
  for all other FUTURE user accounts by default DOESN'T work as some
  process and port monitoring (which runs without mysql user account)
  continuously fills up audit logs which is again Problem.
- Workable solution is to pre-configure some x accounts with passwords
  and enable ALL of them in auditing from Day1. Activate/Deactivate one
  account every quarter one-by-one. Reusing same accounts with
  different passwords once all accounts have been used.

Looking for More efficient solution or if someone has managed to work out similar issue using audit filtering rules?

Comment: How is that "process and port monitoring" thing connecting to the database without a mysql user account?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can find a way for your monitoring software to use an actual account, and further assuming your list of trusted/non-audited users is more static, then using the "exclude user" options should mean less maintenance.

To exclude a list of trusted users from being logged, the MariaDB audit plugin has a [`server_audit_excl_users`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin-log-settings/#excluding-or-including-users) option, and similarly the Percona audit log plugin has a [`audit_log_exclude_accounts`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/management/audit_log_plugin.html#audit_log_exclude_accounts).

BTW, regarding rotating users/passwords, you might be interested to know that MariaDB 10.4+ has an [expiring password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user-password-expiry/) feature.